# Expose ipv6 to virtual machine

Tags: networking, server, virtualization, ipv6, multipass

I have a root server with a single ipv4 address and a /64 ipv6 address range. On the server I have created a virtual machine (with multipass) for running a web server.

For that I have created a rule on the host to forward ports 80 and 443 to the virtual machine (`/etc/ufw/before.rules`):

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-I PREROUTING 1 -i enp41s0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.101.132.173:443
-I PREROUTING 1 -i enp41s0 -p tcp --dport 80  -j DNAT --to-destination 10.101.132.173:80
COMMIT

...

*filter
##############
# Also needed to forward HTTP traffic to multipass virtual-machine instance
-I FORWARD 1 -p tcp -d 10.101.132.173 --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-I FORWARD 1 -p tcp -d 10.101.132.173 --dport 80  -j ACCEPT
```

Now I'd like to reach the web server with ipv6.

From my (beginner's) understanding I can just expose an ipv6 address on the virtual machine (since I have lots of them), there is no need for NAT. Is that true?

If yes, what do I need to configure to expose the ipv6 address? I have Ubuntu 22.04 running on both machines (host and vm).

Answer (score 0):

No configuration on ipv6 is a dream, that will never come true.
You need to do the same you did on Ipv4.

To do:

- Define a fixed Ipv6 Address out of the /64 range on your host, which
  should be forwarded to the VM.
- Multipass uses a dedicated network
  between the host and the VMs. The configuration of this network must
  be extended with IPv6 and the VM needs a fixed ipv6 address.
- Use ip6tables rules like ipv4.

Comment: I think I can do steps 1 and 3, but I am unsure how multipass  virtual machines get their  ip addresses from the host. So I don't know how add the fixed ipv6 address to the virtual machine.

Comment: Hi @topskip step 2 is  a bit ugly, agreeed. did you tink about using docker and container instead of multipass ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I did before and probably will do again now. Next time I try to get SLAAC or something like this running for the local machines.

Comment: all I hat to do with docker was adding ` "ip6tables": true,` to `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and adding `- "[xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xx::x]:443:443"` to my docker-compose file.